# Comparing feature descriptor test?

Tags: opencv, testing, image-processing, feature-descriptor

I would like to test different descriptors (like SIFT, SURF, ORB, [LATCH](http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/projects/LATCH/) etc.) in terms of precision-recall and computation time for my image dataset in order to understand which one is more suitable.

There is any pre-built tester in OpenCV for this purpose? Any other alternative or guideline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code in the foolowing link to compute recall vs. precision curves:
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/desc_evaluation.html#code

In order to plot them, you need to detect keypoint and extract descriptors in each image in the dataset. Next, you write the descriptors for each image in the following format:

descriptor_size

nbr_of_regions

x1 y1 a1 b1 c1 d1 d2 d3 ...

x2 y2 a2 b2 c2 d1 d2 d3 ...
....

### ....

x, y - center coordinates

a, b, c - ellipse parameters ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=1

d1 d2 d3 ... - descriptor values, binary values in case of ORB and LATCH